# ExceptionResolver in Spring MVC without annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, exceptionhandler

How to catch all exceptions in spring-3.0 mvc application?

I tried something like this:

```
public class CustomExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver { ... }
```

and

```
<bean class="com.web.controller.CustomExceptionResolver" autowire="byName">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">uncaughtException</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But it's still not going to that class whenever I encounter exceptions.
I can't use annotations (eg. `@Controller`, `@ExceptionHandler`, `@ControllerAdvice`)

Lastly, how to use `@ControllerAdvice` without annotations? Thanks.

Comment: does [this](http://candidjava.com/spring-mvc-with-simplemappingexceptionresolver-tutorial-and-example) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/) help you

Comment: you getting error when your spring context is getting loaded ? Just defining exception resolver in xml should work

Comment: doesnt spring load those classes by type? you are using byName, maybe thats a reason.